# Theoretical question about notifications in android

Tags: java, android

There are many new and old articles on how to implement notification tracking, but I'm not really about sending them, but about what to use for the background process of tracking them. In fact, I am seriously confused, because on old articles this is implemented using services that are outdated.

I read about WorkManager, which is relatively new, but many say that it is not suitable for notifications. I also found various other options, but according to other developers, they are also not unambiguous.

I hope you will advise me the most suitable option for background work that will not stop even when the application is closed and removed from the "tabs"

Comment: I think the only proper way is to use [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService)

Comment: @Pawel the documentation does not say how long this service works during background operation. Could you tell me if he is subject to termination of his work at an indefinite moment?

Comment: This service operates by being bound by the system which hooks in internal notification listener. I'm rather positive you can't just run it infinitely and it will only be bound to handle possible notification updates but I can't give you specifics.

Comment: @Pawel I listen to the changes in the database and put what I need in the notification. and my goal is to implement a background listening process even when the user is outside the application, based on this, do you think that the service suits me?

Comment: @Pawel and of course happy new year